# how to escape ! while unmarshalling the yamlfile in golang

Tags: go, yaml

I have yaml file which contain special character `!` in the key-value pair as shown below:

```yaml
name: Amit Kumar
age: !kk
address:
  street: !123 Some Random Street
  city: Chennai
  state: TN
  zip: 763098
phoneNumbers:
  - type: home
    number: 0123456789
  - type: work
    number: 0987654321
```

While unmarshall this yaml file, `street: !123 Some Random Street` or `age: !dd`, any word that begin with `!` are removed.
For example:
`person.age` or `person.address` will result in

```yaml
   age: kk 
   address: map[city:Chennai state:TN street:Some Random Street zip:763098]
```

expected:

```yaml
   age: !kk 
   address: map[city:Chennai state:TN street:!123 Some Random Street zip:763098]
```

Any suggestion on retaining the special character while unmarshalling the yaml file?

Go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Address struct {
    Street string `yaml:"street"`
    City   string `yaml:"city"`
    State  string `yaml:"state"`
    Zip    string `yaml:"zip"`
}

type PhoneNumber struct {
    Type   string `yaml:"type"`
    Number string `yaml:"number"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name        string        `yaml:"name"`
    Age         string        `yaml:"age"`
    Address     interface{}   `yaml:"address"`
    PhoneNumber []PhoneNumber `yaml:"phoneNumbers"`
}

func main() {
    // Read the file
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testyamltemplate.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Create a struct to hold the YAML data
    var person Person

    // Unmarshal the YAML data into the struct
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &person)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Print the data
    fmt.Println(person.Age)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unquoted leading exclamation mark is treated by YAML specification as a start of a **tag**.

For prevent such interpretation wrap the whole value with double or single **quotes**:

```yaml
age: "!kk"
street: "!123 Some Random Street"
```